# How to search all entities in JHipster application with Elasticsearch?

Tags: elasticsearch, jhipster, spring-data-elasticsearch

I have created a JHipster monolithic application with Elasticsearch. I also have Elasticsearch enabled, and currently there is a search box for each entity in the UI, and there are the search repositories created for each entity. However, I would like to configure Elasticsearch to search all my entities for the given query in a search box that is located on the menu bar.

Comment: What does your elastic index/type/document structure look like

Comment: I have essentially stuck to the same structure as the default that is provided by JHipster, which is to say that all my entity classes are decorated with the `@Document(indexName = "indexname")` annotation. The Elasticsearch repositories all look similar to: `public interface EntityNameSearchRepository extends ElasticsearchRepository<ClassName, Long> {}`

Comment: I also would like to add that I am currently running the application with the dev profile, so the indices are all stored on the file system, at the default location: `target/elasticsearch/data/elasticsearch/nodes/0/indices` and within that directory are the indices of all my entities in separate folders.